# how to share instance variable between class methods in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, flutter

So I was building a flutter native plugin. I have two method (in `xyzPlugin.m`) which looks like this

```
+ (void)registerWithRegistrar:(nonnull NSObject<FlutterPluginRegistrar> *)registrar {
```

and

```
- (void)handleMethodCall:(FlutterMethodCall *)call result:(FlutterResult)result {
```

Now, I want to share instance variable between both of them.

Suppose. I initialize `meetingView` like this inside `registerWithRegistrar`

```
 MeetingView *meetingView = [MeetingView new];
```

How can I use the same in `handleMethodCall`?

##### What have I tried?

```
@implementation xyzPlugin {
    MeetingView *_view;
}
```

and then in

```
- (void)handleMethodCall:(FlutterMethodCall *)call result:(FlutterResult)result {
    _view = [MeetingView new];
```

but this gives following error

> Instance variable '_view' accessed in class method

Comment: What a point of sharing instance variable? May be you need global variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need a global variable, so you can claim your object with a `static` keyword like:

```
static MeetingView *_meetingView = ...
```

then you can access this object in between class methods in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (instancetype)shared{
    static id obj;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        obj = [self new];
    });
    return obj;
}
// [MeetingView shared]...
```